# Is this process correct for maintaining long-lived Facebook Access Tokens when the user may not have access to the FB account?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-oauth

I am creating a system to allow our clients to create articles and post them in our CMS.  The one feature we are being asked to implement is that when an editor publishes an article, that that article gets posted to the company's facebook wall as well.

The tricky part to this is that the people who are allowed to publish articles may not have login credentials to the company's overall FB account.  This means that I can't rely on the normal process to retrieve access tokens for accounts (or so it seems).

I did quite a bit of research and came up with the following documentation sources:

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/
- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/login-architecture/
- http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

From these it seems that in order to allow locally authorized users to post to the company's facebook wall I must:

- Have a user with valid FB credentials log into an Admin page
- Click a button to start the authorization process
- Retrieve the short term access token from the FB response and exchange it for a long-lived 60 day token
- Store the 60 day token in our database
- Each time a user attempts to publish an article, test if the token has expired and if so alert the admin they need to re-authorize.

Is this the only workflow to accomplish this or is there a simpler method, preferably one that does not require the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a page token. Get it using a long-lived user access token – then the page token will not expire by default.

Comment: Oh perfect, I didn't notice page tokens.  However, looking around it appears that the page token expires when the user access token expires.  Thus I'd still have to use this workflow, correct?

Comment: Nope, it does not expire due to automatic expiration of the user access token. (Only if user changes their password or something.)